# angularjs form validation for jqueryUI date

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui

I have a sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/w9pptd67/6/) where myself trying to validate the date field as,

```
 <div data-ng-class="{'has-error': (myform.fmDate.$touched && myform.fmDate.$invalid)}">
      <input type="text" name="fmDate" id="fmDate" placeholder="Enter from date" ng-model="fmDate" required>
      <ng-messages for="myform.fmDate.$error" data-ng-show="(myform.fmDate.$touched && myform.fmDate.$invalid)">
        <ng-message when="required">Date is required</ng-message>
      </ng-messages>
    </div>
```

But the validation is not hides for date field upon selection.

Answer (score 0):

So, You have given the same name for both the **when**. Change it like shown below.

```
<input type="text" name="fmDate" id="fmDate" placeholder="Enter from date" ng-model="fmDate" required1>
<ng-message when="required1">Date is required</ng-message>
<input type="text" name="test2" id="test2" placeholder="Test 2" ng-model="test2" name="test2" required2>
<ng-message when="required2">required</ng-message>
```

**Try now it will work fine.**

Comment: AFAIK, required is html5 property and  angular use it to validate if that field is required or not. Can u plz provide à fiddle?